# Android - overwrite social share list (via ACTION_SEND)

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, share

I have just implemented wall posting (+login) in an android application (using Facebook SDK) and now I want to use it to "overwrite" the one that already appears in the social share list.

Is this possible? I'm planning to create a implicit intent with my wallposting action, but I don't know how/if it is possible to delete the actual one. Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't know how/if it is possible to delete the actual one

Fortunately, that is impossible, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

The user is welcome to uninstall their earlier app (or disable it on Android 4.0+).